# Mixed Effects or other Model for Binary Interventions and Binary Outcome

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, binary-data

I'm trying to understand the impact of 2 different binary interventions on the completion rate of around 10 courses. The courses all have different baseline completion rates. Intervention one was turned on for all courses at the same time. Intervention 2 was applied to  roughly half of the 10 courses at a later date. I was hoping to do an A/B test but couldn't so now I am trying to model the impact. The dependent variable is "Completed" (binary yes/no). So I have a bunch of rows that look like
`[PersondID | Intervention1 | Intervention2 | CourseIndicator1 | --- | CourseIndicator10 | Completed]`
All variables are binary. There is also a course category label that could be made into another binary indicator variable (4 different categories), and I could potentially add basic demographic data for the user.

A couple of thoughts I had on approaches:

- Does a mixed effects logistic regression make sense here, for repeated measurements among the same course? There are likely not many repeated measurements among the same person, but it is technically possible.In R I believe this would be something like:

```
glmer(completed ~ Intervention1 + Intervention 2 + (1|CourseIndicator1) + ... + (1|CourseIndicator9)),
    data = model_data,
    family = binomial)
```

- There are also a few pairs of courses where the subject matter is more similar than others so I thought I could also do a number of pairwise comparison mixed effects models. I suppose this would be semi equivalent to adding a random effect from a subject matter indicator variable?

Am I on the right path or is there something completely different I should consider?
What is the best way to assess statistical significance after fitting the model?

Thank you!

Comment: *"I was hoping to do an A/B test but couldn't so "* Why not?

Comment: Do you have multiple rows per Person? If yes, the why are there multiple courseindicators, if no, then why is there only one completed?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus due to business restrictions

Comment: @LukasLohse Typically not multiple rows per person, although theoretically possible. The course indicator was supposed to be a one hot encoding of the courses, so then the completed column is a binary indicator of if the one course was completed

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to have a strong reason to consider effect of the course as random and with only 10 different courses I would recommend against random effects, based on the glmm-faq from Ben Bolker, specifically because you probably can't estimate the variance very well:
https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#should-i-treat-factor-xxx-as-fixed-or-random

I would treat course as fixed effects in a normal glm or, if you feel that this makes to many variables, you can use them as strata in a conditional logit model:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/3.5-5/topics/clogit

Also you should rewrite your course variable as one factor column with 10 levels, as  the the current form will probably create linear dependence with the intercept and the R-functions will transform into appropriate dummies of contrasts on their own.